# Java Ticket program with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a program with different types of tickets. I have the `Ticket`, `AdvanceTicket`, and a `StudentAdvanceTicket`. I am printing the price of the ticket $50, advance ticket both options $30 and $40), and both options for student advance tickets $15 and $20.

Both options with the condition being `if daysAhead >= 10`.

I'v spent hours trying to solve this, I need help.

Ticket.java

```java
public class Ticket {
  private int number;

  public Ticket(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return 50.0;
  }

  public String toString() {
     return "Ticket #" + this.number + ", Price: $" + this.getPrice();
  }
}
```

TicketMain.java

```java
public class TicketMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Ticket[] tickets = new Ticket[5];
      tickets[0] = new WalkupTicket(1);
      tickets[1] = new AdvanceTicket(2,12);
      tickets[2] = new AdvanceTicket(3,8);
      tickets[3] = new StudentAdvanceTicket(4,17);
      tickets[4] = new StudentAdvanceTicket(5,7);

      for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
         System.out.println(tickets[i]);
         //System.out.println(" ");
      }
   }
}
```

AdvanceTicket.java

```java
public class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket {
  private int daysAhead;

  public AdvanceTicket(int number, int daysAhead) {
    super(number);
    this.daysAhead = daysAhead;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    if (daysAhead >= 10) {
      return 30.00;
    } else {
      return 40.00;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    if (daysAhead >= 10) {
      return super.toString() + " (" + this.daysAhead + " days ahead, you got a great deal!)";
    } else {
      return super.toString() + " (" + this.daysAhead + " days ahead, you could have saved a bit more)";
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the issue...
StudentAdvanceTicket.java

```java
public class StudentAdvanceTicket extends AdvanceTicket {

  public StudentAdvanceTicket(int number, int daysAhead) {
    super(number, daysAhead);
    super.price = super.getPrice() / 2;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " (ID Required) ";
  }
}
```

This is my desired output.

```
Ticket #1, Price: $50.0
Ticket #2, Price: $30.0 (12 days ahead, you got a great deal!)
Ticket #3, Price: $40.0 (8 days ahead, you could have saved a bit more)
Ticket #4, Price: $15.0 (ID Required)
Ticket #5, Price: $20.0 (ID Required)
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: It's not clear what's going wrong.

Comment: `super.price` ??? 1. there is no such field and 2. even if there was such, private members are not accessible from inheriting classes

Comment: Since `getPrice` is a calculated value in `AdvanceTicket`, you can't simply apply a new value to `price` in `StudentAdvanceTicket`, as `AdvanceTicket` ignores it.  Instead, you'll have to override the `getPrice` method in `StudentAdvanceTicket`, get the `super`'s value and apply your logic to that, before returning it

Comment: I'm not sure if it's something with my JGRASP, but I get an output with a string that is not part of the method... [here's the image](https://img42.com/X9fO0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `getPrice()` for a `StudentAdvanceTicket`, your program actually calls the implementation from `AdvanceTicket`, which will return $30 or $40.

Now when you call `toString()` for a `StudentAdvanceTicket`, it calls `toString` from the `super`, which is the one for `AdvanceTicket`, and that one calls the object's `getPrice()` method, which, again, just returns $30 or $40 and doesn't make use of the `price` member variable.

The correct solution is to override `getPrice` for the `StudentAdvanceTicket` class. In that method, you call `super.getPrice()` and then do the price manipulation with that.

Answer (score 1):

In `StudentAdvanceTicket` there is a compile error because `super.price` cannot be resolved.